# Avoid very fast double clicks

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, mouse

I have a mouse with a weird problem. The left button sometimes fires a double click even if I click just one time.
I would like to know if there's a way to avoid fast double clicks, ignoring clicks with an interval lower than a defined value.
I'm using Fedora 15.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have had it happen to me as well, on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: The mouse is supposed to do that already:  it's called [debouncing](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html).  It sounds like the switch is worn out and is bouncing a lot; it might be easiest to just get a new mouse.

Comment: Not a real answer to your question, as it's not a software solution, but when a mouse of mine becomes old enough to exhibit such behaviour, I tend to open it up, swap the left-button microswitch with that of a button I use less often (means desolder, swap, resolder), and reassemble the casing.

Comment: I think I'll not have another solution, unless buy a new one...

Comment: Same here. Don't even try to fix hardware-problems with software.

Comment: You might get a wider audience, and therefore possibly better answers, on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: @BonsiScott You can't fix hardware problems with software but you can compensate for them.

Comment: If you still have this problem, could you include the make and model of the mouse in question?

Comment: @BonsiScott Very wrong. Having worked a little with electronics production, I can tell that sometimes the only difference between working and nonworking hardware is software calibration. If you read Wyzard's link, you'll see that bouncing is a normal operation.

Comment: Rather than desoldering microswitches, you could try fixing them in-situ like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82z-OpHdBgE)

Comment: I happen to have the same problem. I wanted to upvote the question, but my mouse won't let me. ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xf86-input-evdev-debounce/

after googling for "linux xinput mouse debounce"

I'm not gonna test it. It's been a long time since you asked, but maybe someone has the same problem with a favorite mouse, so here it is. Also, I'm not an Arch user; but they really rock!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @jordanm What do you mean by "include the essential parts of the answer"? Shall the user include the source code? It's a link to a piece software.

Comment: I tried this piece of software and it works well for me. Fixed my double clicking problems. This answer is a gem.

Comment: I've tested it and reported here: http://askubuntu.com/a/616956/6820. In short, it's a good fix unless the contact is TOO bad.

Comment: @pfnuesel In this case, I would say that "include essential parts" would translate to explaining what it does and how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

As I posted in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451864/116842), this should be fixed with libinput 1.9.

[Announce](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2017-October/035469.html):

> Pointer devices now have button debouncing automagically enabled.
>   Ghost button release/press events due to worn out or bad-quality switches
>   are transparently discarded and the device should just work.

Answer (score 1):

A small fix to libinput patch (proposed by @Victor Sergienko) that is reported as "failing to apply" to new libinput versions by some users (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11833).

https://pastebin.com/raw/qa6UP1k1

Answer (score 0):

you can try the option

`Double-Click Timeout`

in mouse preferences, like this http://beginlinux.com/desktop/fedora/mouse-preferences

Comment: This option specifies the the longest possible interval between two clicks to be detected as a double click but the OP needs to specify the shortest possible interval. I have never seen such an option.