# Single clicks register as double-click - software click debounce in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, scripting, hardware, mouse, hid

I need a software click debouncer solution for RHEL/CentOS.  I'm getting intermittent, but frequent, double-clicks registered on single mouse clicks.  The issue doesn't happen on Windows 10 as it seems Logitech (or Microsoft) compensate at the software level.

Similar issues can be solved in Windows with a simple script using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) like:

```
LButton::   
    If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 150) ;hyperclick
        Return
    Click Down
    KeyWait, LButton
    Click Up
Return
```

Or with [Buggy-Mouse.ahk](http://jslover.net/AutoHotkey/Scripts/Buggy-Mouse), but I haven't been able to find a maintained solution for RHEL/CentOS.  There was a Linux port of AutoHotKey named [IronAHK](https://github.com/Paris/IronAHK) but it's last update on github was six years ago.

There's an answer to a similar question at [Avoid very fast double clicks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162813/181898) but the provided solution is for Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be fixed with libinput 1.9.

[Announce](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2017-October/035469.html):

> Pointer devices now have button debouncing automagically enabled.
>   Ghost button release/press events due to worn out or bad-quality switches
>   are transparently discarded and the device should just work.

Comment: Good to know, cheers!